# How do i calculate how long the user used a program according to the DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#

I have a variable: `string currentTime in the constructor:`

```
currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

And in the event Form1_FormClosing i have:

```
currentTimeClosed = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

Now i want to calculate the diffrenece between the two strings times and get the time the user used something like `currenttimeClosed - currentTime = 10 minutes and 10 seconds`
So i know the user used the program 10 minutes and 10 seconds.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Why would you store those values as a string? Just keep the DateTime as an object. Apart from that, use StopWatch or so like everyone else suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you don't need to store *strings* - just store the `DateTime` directly.

You can subtract the two to get a `TimeSpan` telling you the difference and output the value of that.

```
// fields
DateTime currentTime;
DateTime currentTimeClosed;

// Somewhere in constructor
currentTime = DateTime.Now;

// in Form1_FormClosing
currentTimeClosed = DateTime.Now;

var difference = currentTimeClosed  - currentTime;

Console.Write(string.Format("{0} minutes and {1} seconds", 
                            (int)difference.TotalMinutes, 
                            difference.Seconds));
```

Comment: Oded ok its working. How can i make that if still no minute passed so it will show somethingl ike 0 minutes and 23 seconds for example and if a minute or so passed so for example it will show: 2 minutes passed and 23 seconds. And no like now that it show 0.343565465665 minutes and 10 seconds

Comment: @Oded, TotalMinutes is a double.

Comment: @user1434011 - FYI, `Minutes` will go up to `59` only. At that point you may want to use `Hours`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store the dates and times as strings. Instead, use the `DateTime` type:

Declare your variable in the constructor like this:

```
DateTime currentTime;
```

Then, you can assign the date and time upon program startup like this:

```
currentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Whenever you need the running time, compute it like this:

```
TimeSpan runningTime = DateTime.Now - currentTime;
```

Please refer to the [`TimeSpan` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx); `TimeSpan` offers a variety of properties to find out about the amount of time that your program has been running.

Comment: Don't post one liners and I will not be so fast.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values as `DateTime`s, then make the calculation. This will result in a `TimeSpan`, which contains the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use a `StopWatch`.  Create it and store it in a memeber variable and call the `Start()` method in your constructor.  Then call the `Stop()` method in `Form1_Unload`.  You can ask it how low the program was used for with `Ellapsed` or `ElapsedMillis`.